# Error messages with SQL commands SELECT and UPDATE in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update an Access table with the following code:

```vb
strSelectRec = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeDemographics WHERE (LastName) = ('" & strLast & "') AND (FirstName) = ('" & strFirst & "')"
strUpdateRec = "UPDATE EmployeeDemographics SET (Photo)= " & "('" & strPhoto & "')" & " WHERE (LastName)= " & "('" & strLast & "')" & " AND (FirstName)= " & "('" & strFirst & "')"

MsgBox (strSelectRec)
MsgBox (strUpdateRec)
DoCmd.RunSQL strSelectRec
DoCmd.RunSQL strUpdateRec
```

I have tried with and without parentheticals, `tablename.fieldname`, commenting out the `select` statement and run code.

The `select` code throws the error message:

> Run-time Error '2342'  RUNSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.

Without the `select` command, the `update` command throws:

> Run-time error '3144'  Syntax error in Update statement.

What it is supposed to do is just take the path of the picture and update the photo field in the table based on the employee first and last name.

The message box shows the correct file path.

Comment: Post the values of strSelectRec and strUpdateRec you get in the messageboxes

Comment: Not showing complete procedure. Where do values for name and photo variables come from? Cannot 'run' a SELECT query. Action SQL (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE) are 'run'. Names make poor unique identifiers. Should use EmployeeID as criteria for edit actions. All those parens are not needed in UPDATE statement but shouldn't hurt.

Comment: You say path shows in message, so name variables are correctly set as well? Photo is just a text field? Concatenation could be simplified (less &) but shouldn't be an issue. Syntax actually looks fine.

Comment: SELECT * FROM EmployeeDemographics WHERE (LastName) = ('Clinkenbeard') AND (FirstName) = ('Bryan')

Comment: You should edit question with additional info. The SELECT is irrelevant as cannot 'run' SELECT query.

Comment: UPDATE EmployeeDemographics SET (Photo)= ('R:\ID Photos\Clinkenbeard, Bryan.jpg') WHERE (LastName)=('Clinkenbeard') AND (FirstName)= ('Bryan')

Comment: I put in the SELECT statement as a last resort hoping that was causing the issue.  I have commented it out and get the UPDATE error.

Comment: Didn't answer question - Photo is just a text field?

Comment: Yes, all fields are text fields in the database

Comment: for those who wanted to see the whole code:  
Private Sub cmdPic_Click()
Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = False
If f.Show Then
sFile = Filename(f.SelectedItems(1), sPath)
strPhoto = sPath & sFile
End If
strLast = cboLastName.Column(0)
strFirst = txtFirstName.Value
strUpdateRec = "UPDATE EmployeeDemographics SET (Photo)= ('" & strPhoto & "')" & " WHERE (LastName)= " & "('" & strLast & "')" & " AND (FirstName)= " & "('" & strFirst & "')"
MsgBox (strUpdateRec)
DoCmd.RunSQL strUpdateRec
End Sub

Comment: Public Function Filename(ByVal strPath As String, sPath) As String

    sPath = Left(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
    Filename = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
    
End Function

Comment: You should edit question with this type of additional info. Hard to read in comments. However, moot point since compiled query shows variables are populated. If answer does not resolve, then something other than syntax is issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your SQL. Doesn't like parens around field names. Remove all parens and simplify concatenation.

`strUpdateRec = "UPDATE EmployeeDemographics SET Photo='" & strPhoto & "' WHERE LastName='" & strLast & "' AND FirstName='" & strFirst & "'"`